# Thread attached to delegate method in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, methods, delegates

How can I link/attach a delegate implemented method to a new thread in iOS/objective-c? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you read Apple's *[Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)*?

Comment: Can you give a little more context of what you're trying to do?   Generally, the delegate is called on the same thread that the caller is running on.   If you need to spawn a new thread in response to that, you should do so in the delegate itself, usually.